# SQL distinct inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i dont know about this sql, can sql do this

i've table

table : tree_hie

```
cluster | id 
1       | X | Y
2       | X | Y | Z
3       | A | B
```

table : value

```
id | value 
x  | 3
y  | 3
z  | 3
a  | 0
b  | 0
```

and i want to display like this

```
cluster | value | id 
1       | 3     | x,y
2       | 3     | x,y,z
3       | 0     |a,b
```

may you know how to make query like this .. i dont have any idea .. thank you so much..

Comment: normalize the data or you will get in to a world of (programing) pain

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any good mechanisms for processing delimited lists like `X | Y | Z` and joining on them.

Comment: set field `cluster` foreign key in table `value` and then use `join on tree_hie.cluster =value.cluster`

Comment: thanks all 
dagon , barmar , ashkufaraz ..  my database, must be like that.. im just think about foreach.. in php to delimited id on tree_hie , but i cant group it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `replace` to first replace spaces and `|` pipe with comma then you can use `find_in_set`

```
select t.cluster,
min(v.`value`) as value,
group_concat(v.id order by v.id) as id
from tree_hie t
join `value` v on (
find_in_set(
  v.id,replace(replace(t.id,'|',','),' ','') 
  ) > 0
) 
group by t.cluster
```

But its really bad to have a structure like this you should care to have a [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) data structure first

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/316e5/4)

Comment: thanks khalid its working.. but for execute in php can not .. do you know how do it ?

Comment: @tara if you have another question you can ask a new one by adding all details regarding your error

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need a join between the two tables:

```
select th.cluster,
       min(v.value) as value,
       group_concat(v.id) as ids
from tree_hie th join
     value v
     on concat('|', th.id, '|') like concat('%|', v.id, '|%')
group by th.cluster;
```

You have stored a list of ids in a single field, with a vertical bar as a separator.  This is a bad data structure.  You should be using a junction table instead, with one row per cluster and single id.

EDIT:

If the separator is really `' | '` with spaces:

```
     on concat('| ', th.id, ' |') like concat('%| ', v.id, ' |%')
```

Comment: my database, must be like that.. im just think about foreach.. in php to delimited id on tree_hie , but i cant group it ..

Comment: i dont know gordon, not display anything, i try on mysqlworkbench

Comment: If your separator has a space in it, then you need to take that into account as well.

Comment: wait.. on my table value id has not separator, the separator | just on tree_hie table .. this is right ?

     on concat('|', v.id, '|') like concat('%|', th.id, '|%')

Comment: thanks gordon, i just try everything possibilities with separators.. , but cant working..